# Folic acid dose before conception

Tags: medications, dosage

What is the normal folic acid dosage that should be taken while trying to conceive? The minimum dosage available in my region is 5 mg tablets. Is that an acceptable dose? I read somewhere that the normal dosage is 400 mcg.

Answer (score 2):

***Contact your physician and find out for sure from them. The ranges vary and are different for every women. Below is some answers, but you can't take important medical advice from the internet. Please contact your physician.***

[How much folic acid should you take?](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-and-supplements/lifestyle-guide-11/supplement-guide-folic-acid)

> 14 years and up - 400 micrograms/day
>
> Pregnant women - 600 micrograms/day
>
> Breastfeeding women - 500 micrograms/day

[How much folic acid should I take while trying to get pregnant?](http://www.babycenter.com/404_how-much-folic-acid-should-i-take-while-trying-to-get-pregna_2232.bc)

> The recommended daily intake of folic acid for all women of
>   childbearing age is at least 400 micrograms (mcg), or 0.4 milligrams
>   (mg).
>
> During pregnancy, the recommended dose jumps to 600 to 800 mcg, or 0.6
>   to 0.8 mg.

[How much folic acid do women need?](http://www.womenshealth.gov/publications/our-publications/fact-sheet/folic-acid.html#c)

> Pregnant women need 400 to 800 mcg of folic acid in the very early
>   stages of pregnancy often before they know that they are pregnant.

[Examples of foods that have a large amount of folic acid are:](http://www.motherisk.org/women/folicAcid.jsp)

> grains such as whole-wheat bread. dark green vegetables such as
>   spinach and broccoli. meat such as liver. beans such as lentils and
>   kidney beans.